# Open ports for TCP/UDP in Windows Firewall with Powershell

Tags: powershell, tcp, udp, port, windows-firewall

How can I write a powershell script to open windows firewall ports for specified protocol (TCP or UDP)?

Something like this:

```
$ports = @(843, 943)
foreach($item in $ports){
    # open the ports, 843 for TCP and 943 for UDP
    ...
}

"DONE"
```

I did a search, but cannot find way to specify the protocol.

Comment: `New-NetFirewallRule` ? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554908(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: @sodawillow Wow, you saved my life, can you post it as answer below, so it can help others maybe.

Comment: No problem ! Done as requested, have a great day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems to have saved a life :)

There is a dedicated cmdlet for this purpose : `New-NetFirewallRule`

You can find its documentation here : [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554908(v=wps.630).aspx)